# javascript .replace() does not replace every occurence

Tags: javascript, json, regex, replace

I get the following when retrieving it.

```
var data = {"distinct_id"%3A "2222222222222"%2C"%24initial_referrer"%3A "%24direct"%2C"%24initial_referring_domain"%3A "%24direct"}
```

If I check for `typeof data` I get a String back.

However, when I try to make a proper object out of it by replacing "%3A" with ":" etc the above object does not replace all occurrences but only the first.

`data = data.replace(/\%3A/g,":")` only replaces the first "%3A".

How can I make a proper object out of this with `distinct_id, $initial_referrer as well as we $initial_referring_domain ?`

Comment: Simple test in console proves otherwise: everything is replaced.

Comment: working as expected :- http://ideone.com/NHCElY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing your code proves that your `replace` usage is actually okay, it indeed replaces all occurrences of `%3A`:

```js
var data = '{"distinct_id"%3A "2222222222222"%2C"%24initial_referrer"%3A "%24direct"%2C"%24initial_referring_domain"%3A "%24direct"}';

data = data.replace(/\%3A/g, ":");

alert(data);
```

**However**, regular expressions is not correct approach here, as you also have other encoded entities. Use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) function instead:

```js
var data = '{"distinct_id"%3A "2222222222222"%2C"%24initial_referrer"%3A "%24direct"%2C"%24initial_referring_domain"%3A "%24direct"}';

data = decodeURIComponent(data);

alert(data);
```

Comment: `decodeURIComponent()` is best approach, make it your main answer.